# Setting the DB password in JDBC configuration from csv file? JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to get the datatbase url, password and username from a csv file in the JDBC configuration. The post JDBC requests and query DB.

The main moto is not to touch the .jmx test plan and provide values externally.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) is a [configuration element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) therefore it is being executed **before** any JMeter Variables are initialised.

So the easiest option would be setting url and credentials using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image: JMeter Properties in JDBC Connection Configuration]

Once done you will be able either to set the properties value in *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) like:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
username=root
password=secret
```

Or define them through [`-J` command-line option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

```
jmeter -Jurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname -Jusername=root -Jpassword=secret -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

If you have to use the CSV file you can go for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), in this case you can get first entry in the csv file as `${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}`, second as `${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}`, etc.